# Can I save frequently used Find & Replace patterns in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'd like to be able to build a library or just see a history of regex patterns I've used in Find and Replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Intellij gives you a list of Recent Searches and Replacements found by clicking on the small search icon on the left of the input bar.

[image: Search Icon Dropdown]